# Is it possible to compile jade templates for production usage?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a nodejs/express application. I use jade template system for my templates. When I get template it assembles every time. But I want to increase performance by compiling it. Is it possible in express?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can build a function to be executed at loading time (i.e. at the `app` declarations in express), which will compile all your templates and leave them in memory:

Take this as an example:

```
/**
 * @param   {Object}  app
 *
 * @api     private
 *
 * @summary Compiles the partial dashboard templates into memory
 *          enabling the admin controller to send partial HTMLs
 */
function compileJadeTemplates (app) {
  var templatesDir = path.resolve(
    app.get('views')
   , 'partials'
   );

  var templateFiles
    , fn
    , compiledTemplates = {};

  try {
    templateFiles = fs.readdirSync(templatesDir);
    for (var i in templateFiles) {
      fn = jade.compile(
            fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(templatesDir, templateFiles[i])));
      compiledTemplates[templateFiles[i]] = fn;
    }
    app.set('dashboard-templates', compiledTemplates);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('ERROR');
    console.log('---------------------------------------');
    console.log(e);
    throw 'Error on reading dashboard partials directory!';
  }

  return app;
}
```

Calling the templates in an expressJS controller function this way:

```
/**
 * @param   {String}  req
 * @param   {Object}  res
 * @param   {Object}  next
 *
 * @api     public
 *
 * @url     GET       /admin/dashboard/user_new
 *
 * @summary Returns HTML via AJAX for user creation
 */
controller.newUser = function (req, res, next) {
  var compiledTemplates = app.get('dashboard-templates');    
  var html = compiledTemplates['_user_new.jade']({ csrf : req.session._csrf});
  return res.send({ status : 'OK', message : html});
}
```

In this case, I'm sending the `html` via AJAX; to be appended by the application. In the event that you don't want to do that. You can send the html with these functions:

```
res.write(html);
return res.end();
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I've found express.compile middleware. app.use(express.compiler({ src: __dirname + '/public', enable: ['less']}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

Is it for my question?